# Symfony: Loading specific configuration based on url

Tags: url, symfony, configuration, parameters

I have a standard Symfony 2.2 project with my own little Bundle.
I have a route saying that I have a `/{customer}` and I can read `customer` just fine in the controller, so far so good.

But, I also want to load a configuration called `config_{customer}.yml`, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you need this configuration to be injected into any `services.yml` ? I mean, to be callable via `%parameter%` ? Where does these parameters would be used in ?

Comment: There are many answers to this question, I think you're headed down the wrong path here though. I'm assuming you're putting your `config_{customer}` in the `app/config/` directory. These configs determine how the container is compiled. The customer parameter of your route is not available until after compilation, so this method of changing environments will NEVER work. You can however modify services after compilation, which will work, and you can load configuration files into a service which does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a specific bundle when it matches a given host. That bundle will then load its `services.yml` file.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
acme_hello:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "hello.example.com"
```

Your bundle's service file:

```
# src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
acme_hello:
    param: value
```

See the following URL for more information.
http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html